# Edge orientation of finite triangle-free graphs

Tags: graph-colorings

Given a finite simple graph without triangles, I am interested in conditions ensuring that there exists an orientation of the edges such that the following holds.

There exists no cycle $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{2p},x_0$ of odd length such that for each $0 \leq i \leq p-1$, both edges $[x_{2i},x_{2i+1}]$ and $[x_{2i+1},x_{2i+2}]$ are oriented towards $x_{2i+1}$.

If there is no cycle of odd length at all, any orientation works. If the graph is $3$-colourable, one can also easily find such an orientation. Are there more general conditions on the graph to ensure the existence of such an orientation ?

Comment: @M.Winter  The edges are oriented alternately forward and backward, except that the last edge is unspecified.

Comment: Do you have an example of a graph for which you know that such an orientation does not exist?

Comment: 3-colourable graphs have a homomorphism onto a triangle.  In general, graphs with a homomorphism onto any cycle are examples, with the same proof. Even more generally, if $G$ is an example, anything which has a homomorphism onto $G$ is an example too.

Comment: @M.Winter The [induced subgraph formed by all vertices with distance 2 to a chosen vertex in Hoffman-Singleton](https://www.distanceregular.org/graphs/hs-subconstit.html) does not have such an orientation. And neither does the [Wong graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wong_graph). Both are comfirmed by SAT solvers.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It seems to be a rather limited class of graphs then.